# Button not placing in grid (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    window1 = Window(root, "hello", "500x500")
    Button(root, "Click me", 2, 2, 10, 5)
    root.mainloop()


class Window:
    def __init__(self, root, title, geometry):
        self.root = root
        root.title(title)
        root.geometry(geometry)


class Button:
    def __init__(self, parent, message, row, column, width, height,):
        self.message = message
        self.row = row
        self.column = column
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        tk.Button(parent, text=message, height=height, width=width).grid(column=column,
                                                                         row=row)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run the program the button is being placed at y=0 and x=0 but I have no clue why? Can anyone yell me why or give some suggestions.

Comment: By default, a row is of height zero and a column is of width zero. So, rows and columns that don't have anything in them will be invisible and take up no space.

Comment: so does the code think that there is nothing being displayed?

Comment: All you have is one `Button` widget positioned at row=2, column=2.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
tk.Button(parent, text=message, height=height, width=width).grid(column=column, row=row)
```

change with this:

```
tk.Button(parent, text=message, height=height, width=width).grid(padx=column, pady=row)
```

or

```
tk.Button(parent, text=message, height=height, width=width).place(x=column, y=row)
```

You may be interested: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-grid-method-in-tkinter/

Answer (score 0):

As I said in a comment, rows and columns with nothing in them take up no space, and the only gridded widget you have is a custom `Button` at position `row=2, column=2`.

You can change that and make tkinter consider even empty rows and columns by configuring their relative "weights" using the `rowconfigure()` and `columnconfigure()` methods as shown below. Here's some [documentation](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/grid-config.html).

```
def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    window1 = Window(root, "hello", "500x500")

    # Specify minimum grid row and column sizes for a grid of given dimensions.
    height, width = 5, 5
    for column in range(width):
        root.columnconfigure(column, weight=1)

    for row in range(height):
        root.rowconfigure(row, weight=1)

    Button(root, "Click me", 2, 2, 10, 5)
    root.mainloop()
```

If you make the changes shown above to the `main()` function, you should get something like this instead of the `Button` being in the upper left corner.

[image: screenshot]